# Add a secondary ObjectMapper in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, objectmapper

I want to use the default ObjectMapper almost everywhere in my application.
However, there is a specific request that I need to sent to a third party that requires different ObjectMapper.

There are lots of posts on how to customize the default mapper, but I was not able to find a single one explaining how to add an ObjectMapper without replacing the default one.

I tried adding @Qualifier, adding a name to the @Bean, even creating a new class that subclasses ObjectMapper, to no avail. As soon as I add any kind of ObjectMapper, the default one always gets replaced.

Can someone provide an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't let Spring manage it - Just new it up where you need it.

All of the Spring auto configuration for Jackson will back off when you supply an `ObjectMapper` bean. As an alternative, you can also `@Autowire` in `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`, which the Jackson auto configuration uses to create the default ObjectMapper instance. Invoke [`Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder#build`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html#build--) to create a new `ObjectMapper` instance.